# I have to manually change the DNS suffix order every time I connect to VPN. Can I change this permanently or fix the problem somehow?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

Sorry in advance but I'm a programmer, not a network engineer, so I'm a noob at this stuff.  Anyway, when I am *not* connected to VPN from my work PC at home, I have the following DNS suffixes listed (real domain names substituted):

1. enterprise.org
2. network.org
3. company.com
4. us.enterprise.org

After connecting to VPN, one more DNS suffix is added to the very top of the list:

problem-domain.com

At this point, most network functions that I can normally perform when actually connected to the LAN in the office are unusable.  I get error messages about the network paths not being found and what-not.  Anyway, I played around with the suffixes and realized that if I just moved problem-domain.com down one spot to the second in the list, all the problems went away.

Unfortunately, it returns to the top spot every time I reconnect, and I tend to get disconnected frequently.  Is there something else I can do about this or should I just contact the IT department?  I've had this problem before and they weren't able to resolve it but I suppose it would be worth trying again if I could get a different person on the job.

What I don't understand is that I thought it didn't matter what order the suffixes were in?  Isn't Windows supposed to go through each suffix until it finds a match (or has gone through all the suffixes)?  Why is it quitting after the first one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What VPN client / server setup is this??
Sounds like the dns the vpn passes to you is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the DHCP server for the VPN is setting this.  Check with your IT department, or turn off DHCP for your VPN.  If you think of doing that, check with your IT department too - you might mess things up for other people if you choose a static IP address that is in use or in the DHCP pool.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, definitely talk to your internal IT people who are responsible for administering this
2. It's possible that problem-domain.com has DNS that automagically responds to all DNS requests with a record pointing to their own IP block, typically to send traffic to a "domain not found" page with ads. This is called [DNS hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking).